# Skrollr.js: Looping action that will happen all the time while user is scrolling window

Tags: jquery, loops, scroll, jsfiddle

Surprisingly, I can't find an answer to this question in Stack Overflow. Seems no one has a need for what I'm specifically after. However, Skrollr has no real documentation I can find, so there's really no way of finding out how exactly this plugin works; unless, of course, one takes apart the code and investigates.

The following (what you'll see in the jsFiddle project linked below) is what I have. But what I want is to create a **loop** here so as not to have to include `data-X` tags *ad infinitum* in my code. The idea is that this Skrollr script must work on a page that will be as long as the content, which is retrieved from MySQL. So it could be 1,000px long in one instante, for example, and then 50,000px long, as it were.

In such cases, I don't want to have to worry about Skrollr. I just want the animation to go on for ever as the user scrolls the window.

Any ideas? I've tried to build a couple of jQuery workarounds, but I can't get to the bottom of how the Skrollr.js script is doing what it does, so I can't 'fix it.' To make things worse, and adding to the Skrollr Mystery, the full `skrollr.js` and the `skrollr.min.js` do not work the same! Actually, it seems the full version, for some strange reason, is not working properly, whereas the 'minified' version of Skrollr works fine. The normal `skrollr.js` (a) doesn't work in jsFiddle **at all** and (b) when I try it out in my localhost, it goes through the items once and then stops... Anyway, this just adds to the frustration, but is not the key issue. **[ EDIT:** Apparently, this is not a general issue. @Prinzhorn, who created the Skrollr plugin, was kind enough to look into my jsFiddle and says (as you can read in the comments) that the full .js is working for him. **]**

**[HERE YOU HAVE THE JSFIDDLE PROJECT WITH ALL THAT NEEDS TO BE KNOWN!](http://jsfiddle.net/2aHNh/4/)**

Basically, as I said above, the idea is to have the *one, two, three, four, five, four, three, two, one...* constantly iterating up and down, up and down, while the user scrolls the window.

### CONCLUSION

I'm keeping this as *unanswered* a while longer to see if we can come up with an answer on the "modulus operator" issue opened as another possibility due to the fact that Skrollr is not designed for the specific purpose for which I need it. However, I'm working on something else that could possibly work together with Skrollr. So I'm opening a new topic **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013735/skrollr-js-followup-dynamically-set-attributes-according-to-window-height-y)** if you want to check it out.

Comment: That's nothing skrollr is designed for. Just listen for `scroll` and do some simple math on the current scroll position (hint: use the modulo operator).

Comment: Prinzhorn, thanks for linking me to the Skrollr docu. on my other question! Hadn't been able to find it before. Well, on this issue, if the creator of Skrollr tells me it can't be done, then I guess we can close the lid on it. But, correct me if I'm wrong, if I set up a scroll listener using the modulo operator wouldn't I get animation intervals that change according to content length? Or is there a way of maintaining them always equally spaced? (By the way, any idea why the skrollr.js and skrollr.min.js were each acting differently for me.)

Comment: "Or is there a way of maintaining them always equally spaced?" that's why I said use modulo. If you do `scrollPos % 800` you effectively slice the content height in 800px intervals. "any idea why the skrollr.js and skrollr.min.js were each acting differently for me." I replaced skrollr.min.js with skrollr.js in your fiddle and nothing changed.

Comment: Ok, thanks again Prinzhorn! I'm looking into using the modulo operator right now, and with your recommendation it might just work. (By the way, if it weren't for this capricious need of mine, your plugin is one of the coolest there are. In fact, I'll be using it still, for certain animations that do not have to loop for ever.) On the full .js not working for me: that's strange. I guess something odd was going on. In any case, I'll edit my question to say this apparently is not a general issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again, @Prinzhorn. One key problem I'm having with using the modulus operator is the fact that when a user scrolls the scroll position does not go through every single number position (every single pix). For instance, imagine I set to `scrollPos % 100` so that something happens every 100th pix scrolled, the scroll, for example, jumps from 99 to 102, so it never lands on 100 and the action is not called. In the example I'm working, my scroll only lands on 700 and 1600. How would you work around this??

Comment: Why does it only do `700` and `1600`?

Comment: If I set up a modulus operation function like `if(scrollPos % 100 == 0) { //do something }` it will only do that something when it scrolls over 100, 200, 300, etc. But the scroll skips over some numbers. In this example, the only nos. it lands on that meet the modulus operator `if` instance are 700 & 1600, and thus it does something. I set another function to test this our `var s = $(window).scrollTop(); $('.b').empty().append(s+' px');` and I can see how some numbers are being skipped as one scrolls. How did you get Skrollr to trigger something at a precise point in the scroll sequence??

Comment: @Prinzhorn, you can see for yourself here: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/wYGJs/). Of course the numbers it lands on won't be 700 and 1600, as it varies according to window height. But, at a first glance, it seems to be 1100, 3700, 4800 and 7400, and no other numbers that meet the `scrollPos % 100` condition. If you use `scrollPos % 800`, which was your example you'll see it doesn't respond every 800px, but only at the 800px-interval which the scroll happens to fall on during its scroll (please excuse the redundancy).

Comment: @Pinzhorn, at the end I've gone this way with it: (**[link](http://jsfiddle.net/BuwSg/5/)**), which continues using your Skrollr script but dynamically sets the `DATA` attributes to those needed for animation when element is in viewport. However, I'm still working on it, as I'm up to where the attributes are set and now I need to make them occur differently for each and in the the *one, two, three, four, five, four, three, two, one, two, three... etc.* sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not the answer I was expecting, but it certainly sets me on the right track! @Prinzhorn, creator of the Skrollr plugin, says: **"That's nothing skrollr is designed for. Just listen for scroll and do some simple math on the current scroll position (hint: use the modulo operator)."**

So that's that. I'm basically just copying *his* answer. So thanks a bunch for your help, @Prinzhorn!